# Changing the layout of SurfaceView on nVIdia Shield turns the screen black

Tags: android, nvidia, android-tv

I am rendering a video on a SurfaceView in my android app, and I want to resize the surface to match the video size. I do this by setting a new Layout like so:

```
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams videoLayout = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);

    videoLayout.leftMargin = x;
    videoLayout.topMargin = y;
    view.setLayoutParams(videoLayout);
```

Seems to work fine on other android tv boxes but on nVidia Shield the screen goes black. It only works if width and height match the actual resolution, for anything other it's just black.
Also works if I render on a TextureView, but then I take a big performance hit.

Also tried with setFixedSize, same outcome.

```
view.getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);
```

Comment: Update on this, as I just realized the screen doesn't go black but the other SurfaceView on top of it does.
So I have 2 SurfaceViews, one on top which is used for overlays and is transparent, and one on the bottom which is used to render the video on. This works fine on other boxes and even on the Shield, as long as they are the same size! But if the video is not 1080P then it's surfaceview is resized and for some reason the overlay surfaceview turns black as soon as I render the first frame. I check that by switching the order of them with setZOrder, but then I can't see the overlays.

Comment: Setting the overlay view as TextureView seems to work, but it is way more sluggish.
So it seems that the Shield has an issue compositing 2 SurfaceViews of different sizes and somehow turns one of them completely black?